Wolfram Mathematica - Why I can't ReleaseHold y'[x]?
For some reason, y'[x] is equal to 22/13, and I cannot delete it in any way I know or I have investigated.
I tried Clearing All with ClearAll["Global`*"] and ReleaseHold[Derivative[1][y][x]], but nothing works.
I was trying to implicitly derive x^3 y + x^2 y^3 = 10, but for some reason y'[x] was being equal to 22/13, and I don't know why because I haven't written y'[x] = 22/13 in my code before and this is a clean installation of Wolfram Mathematica
Sorry for the trouble and thank you
Screenshot of the error

Try to save your work if the notebook contains important information. Then exit MMA and restart it and enter your information again. You likely typed in something that did things that you did not understand or expect.

You won't believe me, but I tried that before and it didn't work but then, when I read your comment, it worked! That's so strange  Thank you so much!
